# Getting curl to output HTTP status code?

Tags: http, curl, status

I'm using `curl` at the command line on Linux to issue HTTP requests.  The response bodies are printed  to standard out, which is fine, but I can't see from the man page how to get curl to print the HTTP status code from the response (404, 403 etc).  Is this possible?

Comment: As for me, I can see from the manual how to get the HTTP status code, but the option -w does not work. I have reported the bug to Apple.

Comment: The `-i` flag, as in `curl -i https://www.example.com/`, is probably what you want, as per https://superuser.com/a/514798/190188

Comment: Why not just something like `curl -IL http://www.example.com | grep "^HTTP\/"` ?

Comment: Not to future self: the answer you want is probably Cyril David's (currently in 4th position)

Answer (score 941, accepted):

This should work for you *if* the web server is able to respond to HEAD requests (this will not perform a `GET` request):

```bsh
curl -I http://www.example.org
```

As an addition, to let cURL follow redirects (3xx statuses) add `-L`.

Comment: NB: `curl -I` does a HEAD HTTP request, which can be problematic for testing the HTTP status code for some web application servers and services

Comment: And to get just the status number, pipe it to `head -n 1|cut -d$' ' -f2`

Comment: Don't forget to redirect curl's stderr: `curl -I http://www.example.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2`. Add -L to curl if you need the final status after redirects.

Comment: Following the redirect after only doing a HEAD request may cause interesting behavior, depending on how the app is programmed.

Comment: `curl -I -X GET` will send a GET request, but give the same output.

Comment: Here are two working examples, for GET and HEAD -- http://superuser.com/a/1092635/3004

Comment: Forwarding stderr to /dev/null is not neccessary if you only want to suppress the progress bar - use `-s` switch for that.

Comment: Not useful for testing services that return status codes for other methods than GET. Like, REST services.

Comment: This command shows only some info. I can't see my response. "-i" may be better.

Comment: The right way to extract the status number is using `-w` as in `curl -so /dev/null -w 'URL: %{url_effective} at ServerIP: %{remote_ip} and Response: %{response_code}\n' google.com`

Comment: You need to use this solution (-I) if you want to check that a URL is redirecting somewhere else. Without it, you won't get any output.

Comment: why this answer was accepted? the -I switch not only interferes with the header sent and method, but it also compromises the ability to receive the response. there is no objective justification to change the header just to see that status code which is received anyway

Comment: can also use `--head` for the more verbose version of `-I` that does the same thing, but might read more inuitively

Answer (score 1445):

A more specific way to print out **just** the HTTP status code is something along the lines of:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```

A lot easier to work with in scripts, as it doesn't require any parsing  :-)

The parameter `-I` might be added to improve response load performance. This will change the call to a `HEAD` call which will fetch response overhead only, without the body.

**Note:** `%{http_code}` returns on first line of HTTP payload ([available variables for the `-w` option on the `curl` documentation page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-w))

i.e.:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```

Comment: -w "%{http_code}" is the bit that prints the status code. You can add a newline or two in there to separate the code from the body (-w "\n\n%{http_code}\n")

Comment: Wow, this `/dev/null` thing even works in the Windows version of curl that I'm using.

Comment: I believe this downloads the entire file even though it all goes to /dev/null, so not ideal for checking the status code for huge files. `httping -c 1 -s -G -m` issues a GET and doesn't download the whole file, although I realise this question is specifically about curl.

Comment: @romkyns, you're correct: the first variant in my answer downloads the entire file and "saves" it to `/dev/null`, but the second variant - ie. the one using the `-I` option for `curl` - doesn't.  However, care must be taken, as you're not really testing the same action: one does an HTTP `GET` request, whilst the other makes a `HEAD` request... some webservers/websites will respond with a different status code, even if the requested URL is exactly the same!

Comment: FYI: `-s` = Don't show download progress, `-o /dev/null` = don't display the body, `-w "%{http_code}"` = Write http response code to stdout after exit.

Comment: ...and `-I` =  *Show document info only*

Comment: Are the quotes around the "%{http_code}" required ?

Comment: I had to add '-LI' param just before the URL to be able to correctly get the last status after a redirects rather than the '302' (based on @mahatmanich answer): curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -LI http://www.example.org/

Comment: As Maksym noticed you will need to add `-L` in order to follow redirects, otherwise your status code will simply be 302 every time you encounter a page that has moved with a 301 or 302.

Comment: @HakanBaba - The quotes are optional, but if you want to include newline or other escaped characters you'll need quotes.

Comment: for windows, use -o Nul rather than /dev/null

Comment: @Ajedi32 I’m pretty sure no command can write anything to stdout _after_ exit… ;-)

Comment: The flag `-w` is shorthand for `--write-out <format>` which is described as "display information on `stdout` after a completed transfer" I wish there was a `--write-err` to do the same thing, but on `stderr` so you could collect it separately. Any suggestions?

Comment: I used this way massive and end up with errors: error: open /dev/null: too many open files

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, as it works for all kinds of http requests.

Comment: This worked well and should be the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Recent versions of curl can write to `stderr`. From the man page under `-w`: "`stderr` From this point on, the `-w`, `--write-out` output will be written to standard error. (Added in 7.63.0)". So you can use `-w "%{stderr}%{http_code}"` to write the status code to `stderr`.

Comment: FastAPI was giving me 405 (Method not allowed) with the `-I` option, but this works for me.

Comment: Since I have a `.curlrc` file which instructs curl to always print request and response headers I had to add `-q` as the first option in order to only get the return code.

Comment: [`-S`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/curl/curl.1.en#S,) might be in order here.

Comment: Just a note (from my mistakes):
 - the [`-w` option](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-w) uses `%` to get variables; `%{http_code}` (not the `${http_code}`; that's [substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution))! 
 - when redirecting curl output using [`-o /dev/null`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-o),  be careful **not** to redirect using [the `>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) , this will hide the `-w` information, as *everything* is sent to `/dev/null` ; this is **wrong**: `-o > /dev/null`

Comment: I'm not very versed on this sort of stuff, but just to note that when I used this in my use case, it appended the http response code at the end of the response json instead of just returning the code itself, so I ended up having to do this to extract just the code `httpCode=\`echo "$response" | grep -o '.\{3\}$'\``. To be fair though, I actually needed to print the response anyway and use the code for another thing down the line, so 10/10, +1

Answer (score 509):

You can print the status code, in addition to all the headers by doing the following:

```
curl -i http://example.org
```

The good thing about `-i` is that it works with `-X POST` as well.

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer (which does a HEAD request).

Comment: Maybe obvious, but `-i` does work with **any** HTTP method, not just `GET` and `POST`... :)

Comment: the best answer as it makes curl output both headers and body, making it suitable for most of the tasks when used in a script

Comment: This is the best answer, and can be used in conjunction with `-s` (don't show progress meter or error messages) and `-S`(do show error messages after all)

Comment: Sorry if one wants only the HTTP status code this answer is not doing that. pvandenberk's answer that sends the output to /dev/null` does output only the three digit HTTP code by then requesting only the HTTP code in the format output.

Comment: If you just want the line with the status code on (e.g. `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content`), you can do `curl -i http://example.org | head -n 1`

Comment: I wanted to upvote this post, but it currently has 404 upvotes. That's just too pretty to ruin it ;)

Answer (score 291):

If you want to see the header as well as the result you can use the verbose option:

```
curl -v http://www.example.org
curl --verbose http://www.example.org
```

The status will appear in the header. E.g.

```
< Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 19:12:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the verbose flag provides the extra details. Great for testing REST apps.

Comment: +1 very easy to use when doing POST request (curl -v --data "...")

Comment: It even splits them in two different file outputs (http status details to stderr and response body to stdout)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answers the question an a bit more, and it's not limited to a HEAD request.

Answer (score 95):

If you want to capture the HTTP status code in a variable, but still redirect the content to STDOUT, you must create two STDOUTs. You can do so with [process substitution >()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) and [command substitution $()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

First, create a file descriptor `3` for your current process' STDOUT with `exec 3>&1`.

Then, use curl's `-o` option to redirect the response content to a temporary fifo using command substitution, and then within that command substitution, redirect output back to your current process STDOUT file descriptor `3` with `-o >(cat >&3)`.

Putting it all together in `bash` `3.2.57(1)-release` (standard for `macOS`):

```
# creates a new file descriptor 3 that redirects to 1 (STDOUT)
exec 3>&1 
# Run curl in a separate command, capturing output of -w "%{http_code}" into HTTP_STATUS
# and sending the content to this command's STDOUT with -o >(cat >&3)
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) 'http://example.com')
```

Note that this doesn't work in `/bin/sh` as [SamK noted in the comments below](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code/862395?noredirect=1#comment2054144_862395).

Comment: That's serious slickery...and I like it!

Comment: Now how, in turn, can I redirect the output to another variable?

Comment: The output is in `STDOUT`, so you should be able to redirect output from the command to anywhere you like just like a regular command. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: Does not work with /bin/sh.

Comment: good answer, you can also redirect to a real file and cat it later if you want portability of shells

Comment: Is it necessary to close the file descriptor (`exec 3>&-`) after curl has finished?

Comment: Good, bug fails in cygwin, Warning: Failed to create the file /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory.  Use -o curl_res.txt

Comment: If you want it in a variable, but don't want the whole response body to STDOUT, you can do this.

HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null 'https://example.org')

Comment: Once the output is redirected to &3 it's unbuffered and gone so you can't redirect it further. Try this to get both. By sending the output back to stdout (&1) using process substitution, you can reorder things so the response code is followed by the output. This makes it easy to read the status and body into variables because read gobbles up everything after the status line and stuffs it into the "body" variable.
```IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' http_status body < <(curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -o >(IFS= read -r -d '' -u0 stdin; printf "%s"  "$stdin") $URL)```

Answer (score 58):

Redefine curl output:

```
curl -sw '%{http_code}' http://example.org
```

Can be used with any request type.

Comment: -k (--insecure) is overriding -s (silent).

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer -- no odd workarounds with file descriptors, hacky processing of human-readable text with `sed`, extra unwanted text output…

Answer (score 55):

Status code **ONLY**

```
[0]$ curl -LI http://www.example.org -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s
[0]$ 200
```

All credit to this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/drobune/e03d64ef7ba02864781a)

Comment: This one works like a charm, specially when using curl between Docker containers. I use it like this in PHP: `exec("curl -LI "my service name"/"the file I'm looking the HTTP code for" -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s")` (e.g.: `exec("curl -LI static/someimage.jpg -o [...]` where "static" is the service name defined in Docker Compose). Thanks!

Comment: I would get rid of the -I so it does a normal GET instead of a HEAD request.

Answer (score 21):

This is a painful `curl --fail` limitation. From `man curl` :

> -f, --fail
>       (HTTP)  Fail  silently  (no  output at all) on server errors

But there is no way to get both the non-zero return code **AND** the response body in stdout.

Based on [pvandenberk](https://superuser.com/users/101386/pvandenberk)'s answer and [this other very useful trick learned on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292136/636849), here is a workaround :

```
curl_with_error_code () {
    _curl_with_error_code "$@" | sed '$d'
}
_curl_with_error_code () {
    local curl_error_code http_code
    exec 17>&1
    http_code=$(curl --write-out '\n%{http_code}\n' "$@" | tee /dev/fd/17 | tail -n 1)
    curl_error_code=$?
    exec 17>&-
    if [ $curl_error_code -ne 0 ]; then
        return $curl_error_code
    fi
    if [ $http_code -ge 400 ] && [ $http_code -lt 600 ]; then
        echo "HTTP $http_code" >&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```

This function behaves exactly as `curl`, but will return 127 (a return code non-used by `curl`) in case of a HTTP code in the range [400, 600[.

Comment: Agreed, not being able to see the error output is a painful limitation of the otherwise very handy --fail. How can you diagnose a REST api failure without seeing the error output? It's so unfortunate that the curl maintainer bagder stubbornly insists on not providing a --fail-but-show-error. https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1978

Comment: As stated in documentation, it doesn't work for 401 and 407 HTTP code :(

Comment: Thanks to a colleague, I discovered `--fail --show-error`

Comment: [As of 2021](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/8a964cb217b0cd84783da5ba32b18944fc43feb1) you can now use the [`--fail-with-body` option](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/cmdline-opts/fail-with-body.d)

Answer (score 17):

This will send a request to url, get only the first line of the response, split it on blocks and select the second one.

It contains the response code

```
curl -I http://example.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does and how it addresses the problem given by the OP? Unexplained code can appear untrusted and dangerous to users.

Comment: Sure, we send a request to url, get only the first line of the response, split it on blocks and select the second one. It contains the response code that OP is looking for.

Answer (score 15):

For a POST request, the following worked:

```
curl -w 'RESP_CODE:%{response_code}' -s -X POST --data '{"asda":"asd"}' http://example.com --header "Content-Type:application/json"|grep -o  'RESP_CODE:[1-4][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following cURL command and pipe it to grep like so:

> $ curl -I -s -L http://example.com/v3/get_list | grep "HTTP/1.1"

Here's what each flag does:

- `-I`: Show only response headers
- `-s`: Silent - Don't show progress bar
- `-L`: Follow `Location:` headers

Here is a link to [HTTP status codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Run from the command line. This curl runs in silent mode, follows any redirects, get the HTTP headers. grep will print the HTTP status code to standard output.

Answer (score 7):

An example of how to use the response codes. I use this to re-download Geolite databases only if they have changed (`-z`) & also following redirects (`-L`):

```
url=http://example.com/file.gz
file=$(basename $url)

response=$(curl -L -s -o $file -z $file $url -w "%{http_code}")

case "$response" in
        200) do_something ;;
        301) do_something ;;
        304) printf "Received: HTTP $response (file unchanged) ==> $url\n" ;;
        404) printf "Received: HTTP $response (file not found) ==> $url\n" ;;
          *) printf "Received: HTTP $response ==> $url\n" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is some curl command that is using `GET` and that returns the HTTP code.

```
curl -so /dev/null -w '%{response_code}' http://www.example.org
```

Please remember that the approach below is using `HEAD`, which is faster but it may not work well with some web less compliant HTTP servers.

```
 curl -I http://www.example.org
```

Comment: Not working on OS X at least.

Comment: Working fine for me on OS X High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 6):

```
curl -so -i /dev/null -w "%{http_code}"  http://www.any_example.com
```

This will return the following information:

1. response data, if any data is returned by API like error
2. status code

Comment: This doesn't follow redirects. This existing answer is better https://superuser.com/a/442395/475508

Comment: Sure, you can refer that as well!!

Answer (score 5):

Split output content to `stdout` and HTTP status code to `stderr`:

```
curl http://www.example.org -o >(cat >&1) -w "%{http_code}\n" 1>&2
```

If only HTTP status code is desired to stderr, `--silent` can be used:

```
curl --silent http://www.example.org -o >(cat >&1) -w "%{http_code}\n" 1>&2
```

The desired stream can then be picked by redirecting unwanted one to `/dev/null`:

```
$ (curl --silent http://www.example.org -o >(cat >&1) -w "%{http_code}" 1>&2) 1>/dev/null
200
$ (curl --silent http://www.example.org -o >(cat >&1) -w "%{http_code}" 1>&2) 2>/dev/null
<!doctype html>
...
```

**Note** that for the second redirection to behave as desired, we need to run the curl command in subshell.

Comment: Requires `bash` for process substitution.

Comment: @Bruno, I changed the example from https://superuser.com/revisions/1444693/2, as I think the `/tmp/out` `/tmp/err` files can cause unexpected results if run parallel.

Answer (score 3):

The OP wants to know the status code. Often when downloading a file you also want to get a feel of it's size so I'm using curl first to show status code and size of file and then shut off verbose and direct file to the place and name I want:

```
curl -R -s -S -w  "\nhttp: %{http_code} %{size_download}\n" -o /Users/myfiles/the_local_name.html http://archive.onweb.com/the_online_name.html
```

Then I wait for the finishing of curl

```
wait ${!}
```

before I run the next command. The above when used in a script of many commands like above gives a nice response like:

> http: 200 42824
>
> http: 200 34728
>
> http: 200 35452

Please note that -o in curl needs to be followed by the full path of the file + name of file. This allows you thusly to save files in a sensible name structure when you d/l them with curl. Also note that -s and -S used together silence the output but does show errors. Note also that -R tries to set the file timestamp to that of the web file.

My answer is based on what @pvandenberk originally suggested, but in addition it actually saves the file somewhere, instead of merely directing to /dev/null.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ curl -kv https://www.example.org 2>&1 | grep -i 'HTTP/1.1 ' | awk '{print $3}'| sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

- 2>&1: error is stored in output for parsing
- grep: filter the response code line from output
- awk: filters out the response code from response code line
- sed: removes any leading white spaces

Answer (score -1):

There is another way by using Powershell command which is alias to curl.exe
Just type the following:

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://your.website).StatusCode

Answer (score -1):

In Windows PowerShell:

`curl https:\\www.example.org -Method HEAD`

It's really just an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` though.