# How to split the HTTP error code from the contents in cURL?

Tags: bash, curl

Yes, this is related to [Getting curl to output HTTP status code?](https://superuser.com/questions/272265) but unfortunately not the same.

In a script I would like to run:

```
curl -qSfsw %{http_code} URL
```

where the `-f` option ensures that the exit code is non-zero to signal an error. On success I want to get the (textual) output from the fetched file, whereas otherwise I want to use the error code.

Problem:

- Due to race conditions I must not use more than a single HTTP request
- I cannot use a temporary file for storage of the content

How can I still split the HTTP return code from the actual output?

---

Pseudo code:

```
fetch URL
if http-error then
  print http-error-code
else
  print http-body # <- but without the HTTP status code
endif
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no need to use a temporary file. The following bash script snippet send a single request and prints the exit code of `curl` and the HTTP status code, or the HTTP status code and response, as appropriate.

```
# get output, append HTTP status code in separate line, discard error message
OUT=$( curl -qSfsw '\n%{http_code}' http://superuser.com ) 2>/dev/null

# get exit code
RET=$?

if [[ $RET -ne 0 ]] ; then
    # if error exit code, print exit code
    echo "Error $RET"

    # print HTTP error
    echo "HTTP Error: $(echo "$OUT" | tail -n1 )"
else
    # otherwise print last line of output, i.e. HTTP status code
    echo "Success, HTTP status is:"
    echo "$OUT" | tail -n1

    # and print all but the last line, i.e. the regular response
    echo "Response is:"
    echo "$OUT" | head -n-1
fi
```

`head -n-1` (print all but the last line) requires GNU, doesn't work on BSD/OS X.

Comment: For OS X, substitute... head -n-1 ...with... sed \$d

Comment: the only drawback is this fails to save the body of the actual error response. i ended up forgoing the -f flag and checking the response status code manually