# "IF EXIST" check for a link

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Is it possible to if check a url/file/link and then let curl download it if it exists?

```
if check "https://example.com/blabla/blabla.zip" (
curl ... 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a file in link exist using **`curl`** use **`-I`** flag:

**[-I, --head](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)**

**[(HTTP FTP FILE) Fetch the headers only! HTTP-servers feature the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header of a document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the file size and last modification time only.](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)**

---

```bat
curl.exe -I https://mirror.turbozoneinternet.net.br/videolan/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe | find "Content-Length:" >nul && (
echo / && echo/ Your link/file is Ok, downloading... && echo/ 
curl.exe -# https://mirror.turbozoneinternet.net.br/videolan/vlc/3.0.8/win64/vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe -o %temp%\vlc-3.0.8-win64.exe
) || (echo/ Error^!)
```

---

This is adapted code from **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/272273/969781)** /by **[@pberlijn](https://superuser.com/users/77090/pberlijn)**

---